# How to add a new column based on group by and adding condition to a columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, analytics

I have following code

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    'date': ['2019-02-01', '2019-02-10', '2019-02-25', '2019-03-05', '2019-03-16', '2019-04-05', '2019-05-15'],
    'date_difference': [None, 9, 15, 11, 10, 19, 40],
    'number': [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'text': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

| id | date | date_difference | number | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-02-01 | NULL | 1 | A |
| 2 | 2019-02-10 | 9 | 0 | A |
| 3 | 2019-02-25 | 15 | 1 | A |
| 4 | 2019-03-05 | 11 | 0 | A |
| 5 | 2019-03-16 | 10 | 0 | A |
| 6 | 2019-04-05 | 19 | 0 | B |
| 7 | 2019-05-15 | 40 | 0 | B |

Based on the `text` and `number` column, I want to produce a new column called `test`.
In each group, the `text` column starts from the date in descending order.
When `number == 0`, the step size starts with `1`.
When it finds `1` within the group, the step size is increased by `1`. If there is no `1` in the `number` column within the group, then the step size remains `1` throughout the same group.

I have the following code but could not produce the desired result.

```py
df['test'] = df.groupby(['text', 'number'])['number'].transform(lambda x, step_size=1: step_size if x.iloc[0] == 0 else None)
```

The final table should look like this

| id | date | date_difference | number | text | test |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-02-01 | NULL | 1 | A | 2 |
| 2 | 2019-02-10 | 9 | 0 | A | 2 |
| 3 | 2019-02-25 | 15 | 1 | A | 1 |
| 4 | 2019-03-05 | 11 | 0 | A | 1 |
| 5 | 2019-03-16 | 10 | 0 | A | 1 |
| 6 | 2019-04-05 | 19 | 0 | B | 1 |
| 7 | 2019-05-15 | 40 | 0 | B | 1 |

Comment: My question got deleted. Does anyone know why ?

Comment: Your question is not deleted however it would probably help if you showed the code used to create your test column and what happened when you can it.

Comment: I have updated the code @moken.

Comment: Unclear. A line-by-line description on group A is possible?

Answer (score 0):

My attempt:

```py
import pandas as pd


data = {
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    'date': ['2019-02-01', '2019-02-10', '2019-02-25', '2019-03-05', '2019-03-16', '2019-04-05', '2019-05-15'],
    'date_difference': [None, 9, 15, 11, 10, 19, 40],
    'number': [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'text': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

out = df.assign(
    # We assign the following values to the series name "test"
    test=df
    # Group on "text" -- if we grouped on ["text", "number"] we wouldn't see different numbers within the groups.
    .groupby("text")
    # Apply a chain of methods to the group (a pd.DataFrame).
    .apply(
        lambda g: (
            # We sort "date" in descending order as you mention this partially controls the step size.
            g.sort_values(by="date", ascending=False)
            # We shift "number" forward one period with a fill_value of 1 for any newly introduced nulls.
            .number.shift(periods=1, fill_value=1)
            # Cumulatively sum the shifted "number" values
            .cumsum()
        )
        # This will result in the new series, albeit sorted by descending "date".
    )
    # Drop the "text" level of the new multi-index.
    .droplevel("text")
    # The assign method acts as join, rearranging the newly created series to match the index of `df`.
)
print(out)
```

```
   id        date  date_difference  number text  test
0   1  2019-02-01              NaN       1    A     2
1   2  2019-02-10              9.0       0    A     2
2   3  2019-02-25             15.0       1    A     1
3   4  2019-03-05             11.0       0    A     1
4   5  2019-03-16             10.0       0    A     1
5   6  2019-04-05             19.0       0    B     1
6   7  2019-05-15             40.0       0    B     1
```